# Using VelocityView or plain text in Controller response?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm trying to return content **other than json** in my Controller, but I can't seem to get it to work. Ideally, I'd like to return a rendered velocity template as plain text or html.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "time", headers = "Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody
Date getCurrentTime( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {
    response.setContentType( "text/plain" );

    return new Date();
}
```

And this is in my springmvc-servlet.xml (I know this is not right...but I'm a bit lost here):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.paml.alerter.controller" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
</bean>

<!-- This bean sets up the Velocity environment for us based on a root path 
    for templates. Optionally, a properties file can be specified for more control 
    over the Velocity environment, but the defaults are pretty sane for file 
    based template loading. -->
<bean id="velocityConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/" />
</bean>
```

Does anyone know how to set this up right?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method is annotated with `@ResponseBody`, then the Spring MVC view layer will be bypassed entirely.

If you're not interested in JSON output, then `@ResponseBody` is inappropriate - just remove it, and your Velocity views will be used.

If you need to switch between JSON and some other `View` layer, then you should consider removing `@ResponseBody` and using `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` instead.  See the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations) for how to set this up.

Comment: Removing the @ResponseBody definitely solves half the problem...I think. But now the URL's don't resolve at all. I'll keep digging on it. Do you know if there are any examples of what I'm trying to do? I've looked...none of them seem to line up just right for someone new to these topics.

Comment: Ha - that's honest. I'm just trying to get a controller to return back html or String data that has been rendered by velocity. Ideally I'd like to render an html table in the controller with velocity server side rather than do it with json+javascript client side.

Comment: @javamonkey79: That's pretty basic Velocity config, then - see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity